# Gerando jwt manualmente usando JAVA, mas jwt.io não valida

Tags: java, jwt, sha-256

Estou tentando gerar manualmente o JWT no Java sem utilizar libs, porém o JWT retornado não está sendo validado pela aplicação web https://jwt.io/.

```
public String authenticateUser(String body) {
    try {
        String key = "teste-de-chave-hahaha";
        String header;
        String payload;
        String signature;

        //#################################
        HashMap<String, String> hashHeader = new HashMap<String, String>();
        hashHeader.put("typ", "JWT");
        hashHeader.put("alg", "HS256");
        System.out.println("hashHeader = " + hashHeader);

        JSONObject json = new JSONObject(hashHeader);
        System.out.println("hashHeader json = " + json);

        header = this.getBase64Parsed(json.toString());
        System.out.println("hashHeader json Base64 = " + header);

        //#################################
        HashMap<String, String> hashPayload = new HashMap<String, String>();
        hashPayload.put("iss", "sct.infogruposi.com");
        hashPayload.put("username", "brunokchimbo");
        hashPayload.put("email", "brunokchimbo@hotmail.com");
        hashPayload.put("acl", "Administrador");
        System.out.println("hashPayload = " + hashPayload);

        json = new JSONObject(hashPayload);
        System.out.println("hashPayload json = " + json);

        payload = this.getBase64Parsed(json.toString());
        System.out.println("hashPayload json Base64 = " + payload);

        //#################################
        String token = header + "." + payload;
        String chave = this.getHmacSHA256Encrypted(token, key);
        System.out.println("signature hashHmacSHA256 = " + chave);

        signature = this.getBase64Parsed(chave);
        System.out.println("signature hashHmacSHA256 Base64 = " + signature);

        //#################################
        token = token + "." + signature;        
        System.out.println("token completo = " + token);

        return token;
    } catch(Exception ex) {
        ex.printStackTrace();
    } finally {
        return Response.status(Response.Status.FORBIDDEN).build().toString();
    }      
}

public String getHmacSHA256Encrypted(String value, String key) {
    return HmacUtils.hmacSha1Hex(key, value);
}

public String getBase64Parsed(String msg) {
    return Base64.getEncoder().withoutPadding().encodeToString(msg.getBytes());
}
```

Este código gera o JWT:

> eyJ0eXAiOiJKV1QiLCJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiJ9.eyJpc3MiOiJzY3QuaW5mb2dydXBvc2kuY29tIiwiYWNsIjoiQWRtaW5pc3RyYWRvciIsImVtYWlsIjoiYnJ1bm9rY2hpbWJvQGhvdG1haWwuY29tIiwidXNlcm5hbWUiOiJicnVub2tjaGltYm8ifQ.MmIwOGIxYTliM2Q4NjZhYjc1YmY1N2M4NjJmNTM0YmUzOWQ5NDJkYw

O procedimento que estou fazendo é:

1. Acessar o site https://jwt.io/.
2. Preencher o campo "verify signature" com a chave "teste-de-chave-hahaha".
3. Colar o JWT no campo "Encoded".

Ao realizar tal procedimento com as informações pré carregadas no site, por default, uma mensagem aparece abaixo informando que a chave é válida, porém ao realizar o procedimento com as informações geradas pelo meu código java, a assinatura é inválida.

Qual é a forma correta de gerar o JWT?

Comment: Segui os passos da vídeo aula do Vedovelli no youtube (https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=k3KfK0ZS_FY) e também não validou. Reescrevi todo o código PHP que ele gerou e o token é o mesmo. Copiei e colei lá no jwt.io informando a chave, tudo certinho e nada. Estou achando que a aplicação não serve de base para realizar testes na validação.

Comment: Depois de alguns testes, se eu trocar a senha para 'minha-senha' (vi em https://imasters.com.br/back-end/entendendo-o-jwt), a validação funciona.